# Oracle apex - item value doe not sent on submit

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2, oracle-apex-19.2

I have an item :P3015_VOL (NUMBER field), when I click "save" button I'm doing two things:

1. Dynamic action that sets the item value to 33. Then in debug message I can see that the item does have the value 33.

[image]

[image]

2. in the submit page processing I print again the item's value in debug message:

[image]

Now the Value is NULL

Why is this happening? How can I get the correct value in the processing?

Thanks

Comment: Can you [edit] your question, and include information on what kind of item P3015_VOL is; IE, text, hidden, related to a database table, etc.  Also, please remove one of the [oracle-apex-1#.2] tags, leaving just the version you are having the problem with.

Comment: How are you submitting the page ? Is that another true action in the dynamic action or is there another submit action ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie The submit is done in the processing section, not with dynamic action, when pressing the button "save". (the button also have dynamic action to sets the value of the item to 33 and print it in debug)------------------
MarkStewart The issue is relevant for both Apex versions. also as I mentioned, It's a number field, but probably relevant to all types.

Comment: That is not my question. The dynamic action on the "SAVE" button in your example. How is the submit being done ? Is there another button so submit the page ? It looks like you're posting only a small portion of the code.

Comment: @KoenLostrie There is only one relevant button, which is the "Save" button. It has a dynamic action on click and there is also a process associated with this button that submits the page. Both are happening, first the dynamic action, then the submit process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an item value is calculated on page submit, the best way to do this is to submit the page and perform a computation on submit. There should not be any need for a dynamic action here.
Steps:

1. Create a **Computation** on `P3015_VOL` with point **After Submit**, type **Static Value**, value 33
2. Set the SAVE button action to **Submit Page**

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Glad to be of help.